# XSJS always return exmpty result set from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, sapui5

I'developing a SAPUI5 application. I need to retrive datas from db and I'm using an .xsjs, this is my ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url : "/SimpleProject/services/querytest.xsjs",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(response));
            },
            error: function(e) {
                sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
```

And this is my .xsjs file where I try to query the SAP HANA DB.

```
    try {
    $.response.contentType = "application/json"; 

    var conn = $.db.getConnection();

    var statement = conn.prepareStatement('SELECT * FROM "_SYS_BIC"."TABLETEST"');
    var rs = statement.executeQuery();

    conn.commit();

    if (rs != undefined)
        $.response.setBody(JSON.stringify(rs));
    else $.response.setBody(JSON.stringify("empty record set"));

    $.response.status = $.net.http.OK;
} catch(e) {
    $.response.status = $.net.http.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    $.response.setBody(JSON.stringify(e));
} finally {
    statement.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

If I execute the query from SQL console, it works fine, but from the xsjs return always an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I cannot send the "rs" object as output but I have to build another object as result;

```
    while (rs.next()) {
       var record = {};
        record.npp = rs.getString(1);
        record.prog = rs.getString(2);
        record.sottoProg = rs.getString(3);
        output.results.push(record);
}
rs.close();
```

Now the xsjs works fine.